# Galois group of the polynomial $x^4-2$.

Tags: galois-theory

So I'm reading Conrad's notes: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/galoisaspermgp.pdf and I'm a bit stuck on example 2.3, namely the "effect of $r$ on the roots" part. Having studied the table extensively, I don't see where he gets the fact that say for example, $r(2^{1/4})=2^{1/4}i$.

This is the only thing that is preventing me from grasping the example in full so any clarification on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table says, rather straight-forwardly, that $r(\sqrt[4]2) = i\sqrt[4]{2}$. That's what the second row of Table 1 shows: the values of $r(\sqrt[4]2), r^2(\sqrt[4]2), r^3(\sqrt[4]2)$, and so on.

Comment: Well don't I feel a bit silly there. Thank you very much. Should I leave this question up or delete it?

Comment: @thesmallprint No worries. We all have our moments. And I'd say leave it up, it's not doing much harm.

Comment: I am sorry to ask you a further question. Basically I thought I knew it but I couldn't quite explain it - where does the notion of two generators come from? Where does that initial definition of $r$ come from?

Comment: @thesmallprint Experience, mostly. This is the structure of basically _all_ splitting fields of $x^n-k$ over $\Bbb Q$: One real $n$th root $\sqrt[n]k$, and one primitive $n$th root of $1$, $\xi_n$, with the dihedral group as Galois group, generated by complex conjugation and the order-$n$ "rotation" $\sqrt[n]k\mapsto \sqrt[n]k\cdot \xi_n$ (this transformation is indeed rotating the roots of $x^n-k$, which forms a regular $n$-gon, about the origin).

Comment: @thesmallprint But to be a bit more structured, there are loads of tools you can use. For instance, you could look at intermediate extensions and their Galois groups. You could look at the $4$ roots, and see what permutations on them look promising (there are four roots, and you know the group has order $8$. Lagrange's theorem immediately rules out a lot of permutations, which are left? You can ask which of these may be extended to an actual automorphism of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]2, i)/\Bbb Q$? Or which form a subgroup of order $8$?)