# Find all homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2},i]$ to the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ and its images

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I know, that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2},i]$ has dimension $8$ as a vector space, that means the image, under any homomorphism, should have dimension $\leq8$.
And since $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2},i]\subset$ algebraic closure$(\mathbb{Q})$, I believe that the possible images are all the subfields of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2},i]$. Is my idea correct?

Comment: @DietrichBurde you are correct, I got tangled up. Corrected that in my edit

Comment: Images as what? As vector spaces over $\Bbb Q$ or as fields?

Comment: @Arthur As field homomorphisms

Comment: @MathR All fields only have two ideals: the zero ideal and the field itself. Therefore, all field homomorphisms are either the zero homomorphism (excluded in some definitions) or monomorphisms, i.e. injective homomorphisms.

Comment: @Teddy38 so each Homomorphism between said fields is an isomorphism onto some subfield of the algebraic closure. But I still do not know how these subfields look like.

Comment: Have you done Galois theory? Field extensions, and such? It looks like you are moving into that direction. But, to give a helpful answer we need to know the precise point in your studies. Every time I teach this in a course what would happen is that an answer helpful now may (will?) become routine in two weeks with a bit more theory under the students' belt.

Comment: @MathR Since we are dealing with monomorphisms, the subfields we are looking for must all be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[i,\sqrt[4]{2}]$. However, this field is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, so there is only one subfield of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ which is isomorphic to it. The question boils down to finding automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}[i,\sqrt[4]{2}]$.

Comment: What Teddy38 said. The automorphisms have been described e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3594538/11619), and probably earlier in more detail. You should tell us whether you have the tools to answer questions like: If $\sigma$ is such a homomorphism, what alternatives are there for $\sigma(\root4\of2)$? What about $\sigma(i)$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen the image of $\sqrt[4]{2}$ under an automorphism must be another base element .

Comment: MathR, thanks for sharing. That answer says quite a bit about what you know already. Let's take the next step. Because $\sigma$ is an isomorphism of rings, it preserves products and sums. So
$$\sigma(2)=\sigma(1+1)=\sigma(1)+\sigma(1)=1+1=2.$$
Then the next step
$$2=\sigma(2)=\sigma((\root4\of2)^4)=\sigma(\root4\of2)^4.$$
Do you understand each step in this chain of equalities? What alternatives does that leave for the choice of $\sigma(\root4\of2)$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen yes each step is clear and only the 4 solutions of $x^4-2$ are possible for $\sigma$($\sqrt[4]{2}$).

Comment: Correct! +1 Similarly $\sigma(i)$ must be one of the zeros of $x^2+1$. The next step: Why does knowing $\sigma(\root4\of2)$ and $\sigma(i)$ determine $\sigma$ completely?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen because the splitting field is defined by these two solutions.

Comment: Instead of *defined*, I would say *generated*. But anyway, that's the idea. Now you know that there are at most eight homomorphism - at most one for each pair of choices of $\sigma(\root4\of2)$ and $\sigma(i)$. The last part is to show that all eight combinations actually work. The posted answer uses a general theorem saying that in the case of a Galois extension the number of possibilities is equal to the dimension $[\Bbb{Q}(i,\root4\of2):\Bbb{Q}]=8$. Is this result available to you? Without it this last step may get a bit hairy :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes I have this result available. Since I know, that there are only 8 different automorphisms and We have just constructed 8 automorphisms, these must be all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2},i]$ is the splitting field of $X^4-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. It is easy to check that it factorises as
$$
(X-\sqrt[4]{2})(X-i\sqrt[4]{2})(X+\sqrt[4]{2})(X+i\sqrt[4]{2})
$$

Over $\mathbb{Q}$, splitting fields are Galois extensions, which mean that they have some nice properties: the Galois group has the same order of the extension degree, which is $8$ in this case. So you are looking for $8$ automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2},i]$. These are generated by

$$
\begin{array}{crcl}
\sigma:&i&\to&-i \\
\tau:&\sqrt[4]{2}&\to&i\sqrt[4]{2}\\
\end{array}
$$

So the automorphisms you are looking for are
$$
\{\text{id},\sigma,\tau,\tau^2,\tau^3,\sigma\tau,\sigma\tau^2,\sigma\tau^3\}
$$